# Согласование приложения

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно: "молочно-сбивные массы типа "Птичье/его молоко/а"?

Answer (score 3):

ГОСТ Р 53041-2008. Изделия кондитерские и полуфабрикаты кондитерского производства. Термины и определения:

Сбивные массы разделяют по составу на **сбивные массы типа "Суфле", молочно-сбивные массы типа "Птичье молоко",** орехово-сбивные, фруктово-сбивные.

**Комментарий**

1) Не очень понятно использование **прописных букв**, всё-таки это не имена собственные.

2) **По поводу согласования:** в специальной литературе при наличии кавычек чаще используется И.п., например:

Ротационная БД в ЛВС типа «звезда».

Прошу Вас разработать проект на вновь устанавливаемую УАТС типа "Меридиан-1".

Все медики дают положительную оценку нетканым перевязочным медицинским полотнам типа "Марлин".

А ночью ещё и Барби вскочила и разрисовала шкатулку красивыми узорами типа "ореховое пламя".

Отделочные покрытия ремонтируют и освежают составами типа "Полироль".

Но: Это то, что сейчас печатают в газетах типа "Московского комсомольца".

Comment: *Не очень понятно использование прописных букв, всё-таки это не имена собственные.* - это как раз имена собственные. Названия.

Comment: *в специальной литературе при наличии кавычек чаще используется И.п., например:* - э, нет. тут разные "типы". Есть есть некий сертифицированный тип, и "Птичье молоко" - название этого типа, закрепленное, то несклонение возможно. А если а некоторые отстающие колхозы типа "Красного пахаря" (похожие на "Красный пахарь"), то тут без управления как-то не смотрится совсем.

Comment: Есть торт "Птичье молоко", есть конфеты "Птичье молоко" - это, действительно, названия, а вот по поводу сбивной массы у меня большие  сомнения. Также существуют разные торты-суфле, например, торт Вишневое суфле, Персиковый торт-суфле, то есть суфле в качестве нарицательного существительного входит в названия. Что касается колхоза, то я похожий пример привожу с газетой, где название также склоняется.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе оба варианта допустимы, но лучше все-таки согласовывать: ***молочно-сбивные массы типа "Птичьего молока"***.
Я не вижу, что тут может помешать нормальному управлению. даже родового слова нет, только кавычки как-то оправдывают несклонение, но этого мало.

С кавычками подумайте, как поступить, не очень смотрится тут вложенные одного вида.

Answer (score 1):

Вобщем я так понял, что если речь идет о неком таксоне с именем *тип "Птичье молоко"* - как, например, *подводная лодка типа (проекта) "Комсомолец"* - то это можно и даже рекомендуется не склонять, как название при родовом слове.

а если "типа" означает "похожее" - "алкоголики типа моего соседа" - то склонения трудно обойти.

какой случай тут имеется в виду, сказать трудно. Cкорее всё-таки второй, вряд ли есть некий ***тип, с названием "Птичье молоко"***, это название отдельного продукта или полуфабриката. Так что я за склонение.

Comment: Алкоголики  (какие?) типа  моего соседа -  это несогласованное определение, выраженное  словосочетанием.